# Parse through an arbitrary number of exploded data

Tags: php

Basically, I am asking users to give me their interests separated by commas.  I want to parse through these, and enter them into a SQL database.  Is there a way to parse through arbitrarily based on the number of interests they entered?  Here's my code so far:

```
$interests = $_POST['interests'];
$interests = explode(',', $interests);
```

Comment: foreach loop through the array

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $interests = $_POST['interests'];
    $interests = explode(',', $interests);

    foreach ($interests as $interest) {
        // INSERT INTO db using $interest. Make sure to properly escape each interest!
        // Use PDO and bind parameters to avoid sql injection attacks
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$interests = explode(',', str_replace(Array("\r", "\r"), ",", $_POST['interests'])); // the repalce here is to remove any new lines that might have been added if a textarea field used
$interests = array_filter($interests); // weeds out empty entries that might have been crated
foreach($interests AS $interest) {
  $interest = trim($interests); // remove extra spaces that might be
  // do what you need
}
```

Comment: thanks I didn't know about the array_filter and trim functions